# Two modals opening from a single link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I have some code that opens a modal that contains a form when a marker is placed on a layer in leaflet. It all worked well with out any issues. I copied this code so I could make a second button to control the opening of another modal containing a different form. I changed the link information but when the button is clicked the

```
L.DomEvent.on(link, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop)
                  .on(link, 'click', L.bind(this.startCreating, this));
```

Opens up both forms at the same time or opens one then when closed and clicked againit will open both. Im not sure whats going on because each modal has a different ID.

Here is a live example of the map with the modals. Click the small elements/buttons on the left under the zoom control and drag the new market and click again to set its place on the map.
[Leaflet Map with modals](http://198.71.58.116:85/hurleyforms/pecomap/wfs.html)

Here is the JS code that should call the first modal called eventDataModal. The main link in the code is near the top:

```
L.MarkerControl = L.Control.extend({

    options: {
        position: 'topleft',
        url: 'http://echostorm.mynetgear.com:8080/geoserver/usa/ows',
        userName: 'wfspost',
        password: 'createfeature'
    },

    map: null,
    marker: null,
    binded: false,


    onAdd: function (map) {

        this.map = map;

        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control leaflet-bar'),
            // link = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker', container);
            link = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open', container);

        link.href = '#';
        link.title = 'Create a new visual report';

        link.innerHTML = '';
        L.DomEvent.on(link, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop)
                  .on(link, 'click', L.bind(this.startCreating, this));

        map.on("editable:drawing:commit", L.bind(this.onMarkerAdd, this));                    

        return container;
    },

    startCreating: function() {
        this.marker = this.map.editTools.startMarker();     
    },

    onMarkerAdd: function(e) {
        this.nearestFeature = null;
        this.findNearestPoints(e.layer.getLatLng());
    },

    onFormClosed: function() {
        if (this.marker!=null) {
            this.map.editTools.featuresLayer.removeLayer(this.marker);
            this.marker = null;
        }
    },

    findNearestPoints: function(latlng) {

         var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: 'usa:within5mi',
            maxFeatures: 5,
            outputFormat: 'text/javascript', 
            format_options: 'callback: nearestPoints',
            srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
            viewparams: 'radius:802;lon:'+latlng.lng+';lat:'+latlng.lat,

        };

        var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);

        $.ajax({
            jsonp: false,
            url: this.options.url + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'nearestPoints',
            success: L.bind(this.handleNearestPoints, this)
        });         
    },


    handleNearestPoints: function(data) {           
        this.clearModal();
        this.setModalDate();

        if (data && data.type=="FeatureCollection"
            && data.features && data.features.length
            && data.features.length > 0) {
            this.fillModal(data.features[0]);
        }

        this.openPopup();
    },

    formatDate: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDate();
        return date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+(day < 10 ? "0"+day : day);
    },

    clearModal: function() {
        $('#eventDataModal').find('input').each(
            function() {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        );

        $('#eventDataModal').find('textarea').each(
            function() {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        );
    },

    setModalDate: function() {
        $("#form-patrolDate").val(this.formatDate(new Date()));
    },

    fillModal: function(feature) {
        var props = feature.properties;

        $("#form-region").val(props["Region"]);
        $("#form-circuitID").val(props["Circuit_ID"]);
        $("#form-circuitName").val(props["Circuit_Name"]);
        $("#form-vendor").val(props["Vendor"]);
        $("#form-quad").val(props["Quad"]);

    },

    openPopup: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
        $('#eventDataModal').modal('show');
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        if (!this.binded) {
            $('#eventDataModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', L.bind(this.onFormClosed, this));
            $("#saveEventDataModal").on('click', L.bind(this.onSave, this))
            this.binded = true;
        }
    },

    onSave: function() {
        var properties = this.getFormData(),
            request = this.wfsBody("usa", "usa:pecotest", "geom", properties);
            console.log(request);
            this.makeRequest(request);          
    },

    makeRequest: function(body) {

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: this.options.url,
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "text",
            data: body,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(this.options.userName + ":" + this.options.password)
            },
            jsonpCallback: 'datasave',
            success: L.bind(this.onDataSave, this),
            failure: function(r){console.log("AJAX Failure!");console.log(r);}
        });                 
    },

    onDataSave: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },

    getFormData: function() {
        var result = {};

        $('#eventDataModal').find('input').each(
            function() {
                if (this.type=="checkbox") {
                    result[this.name] = this.checked ? "Yes" : "No";    
                } else {
                    result[this.name]=$(this).val();
                }
            }
        );

        $('#eventDataModal').find('textarea').each(
            function() {
                result[this.name]=$(this).val();
            }
        );

        return result;
    },

    wfsBody: function(namesapce, typeName, geometryField, properties) {
        var xml;
        xml ='<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"';
        xml += ' xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"';
        xml += ' xmlns:usa="http://census.gov"';
        xml += ' xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">\n';
        xml += '   <wfs:Insert>\n';
        xml += '      <'+typeName+'>\n';
        xml += '        <usa:'+geometryField+'>\n';
        xml += this.marker.toGML()+"\n";
        xml += '        </usa:'+geometryField+'>\n';

        for (var k in properties) {
            if (properties.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                xml += "<"+namesapce+":"+k+">";
                xml += properties[k];
                xml += "</"+namesapce+":"+k+">\n";
            }
        }

        xml += '      </'+typeName+'>\n';
        xml += '   </wfs:Insert>\n';
        xml += '</wfs:Transaction>\n';

        return xml;
    }

});

L.Marker.include({
toGML: function(){
    var latlng = this.getLatLng(),
        xml;

    xml = '<gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:coordinates cs=","                
 decimal="." ts=" ">';
    xml += latlng.lng + ',' + latlng.lat;
    xml += '</gml:coordinates></gml:Point>';

    return xml;
 }
});
```

Here is the corresponding HTML for the modal evenDataModal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="eventDataModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-         
        label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Visual Report</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="php\new_peco_visual_report_db_insert.php                 
            method="POST"><div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-priority">ID Code</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form-priority"     
             name="ID_Code" placeholder="ID_Code">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-region">Region</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-region"           
              name="Region" placeholder="region">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-circuitID">Circuit ID</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form-circuitID"      
             name="Circuit_ID" placeholder="Circuit ID">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-circuitName">Circuit Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-circuitName"      
             name="Circuit_Name" placeholder="Circuit Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-patrolDate">Patrol Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="form-patrolDate"       
              name="Patrol_Date" placeholder="Patrol Date">
          </div>                                                                                                            
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-vendor">Vendor</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-vendor"            
             name="Vendor" placeholder="Vendor">
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-repairNumber">Repair Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-repairNumber"     
              name="Repair_Number" placeholder="Repair Number">
          </div>                                                                                                
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-problemDescription"> Problem                      
              Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-                   
             problemDescription" name="Problem_Description"                                
              placeholder="Problem      
              Description">
          </div>                                                                                               
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-urgency">Priority</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form-urgency"         
              name="Urgency" placeholder="Urgency">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-circuitPortion">Circuit Portion</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-circuitPortion"    
              name="Circuit_Portion" placeholder="Circuit Portion">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-quad">Quad</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-quad"                
             name="Quad" placeholder="Quad">
          </div>       
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-location">Location</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-location"                
             name="Location" placeholder="location">
          </div>                                
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-poleSub">PolSub</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form-polSub"             
              name="PolSub" placeholder="PolSub">
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-poleNumber">Pole Number</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="form-poleNumber"    
             name="Pole_Number" placeholder="Pole Number">                                        
          </div>   
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-aerialName">Aerial Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-aerialName"      
             name="Aerial_Name" placeholder="Aerial Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-workRequired">Work Required?</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-workRequired"     
             name="Work_Required" placeholder="Work Required">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-long">GPS Longitude</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-long"             
             name="long" placeholder="long">
          </div>   
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-lat">GPS Latitude</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-lat" name="lat"       
              placeholder="lat">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-notes">Comments</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="form-comments"                   
             name="Comments" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>         
       </form>                                                                    
    </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-                         
          dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-primary"                              
          id="saveEventDataModal">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Here is the code for that should call the second modal called evenDataModal2

```
L.MarkerControl2 = L.Control.extend({

    options: {
        position: 'topleft',
        url: 'http://echostorm.mynetgear.com:8080/geoserver/usa/ows',
        userName: 'wfspost',
        password: 'createfeature'
    },

    map: null,
    marker: null,
    binded: false,


    onAdd: function (map) {

        this.map = map;

        var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control leaflet-bar'),
            // link = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker', container);
            link = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'glyphicon glyphicon-fire', container);

        link.href = '#';
        link.title = 'Create a new thermal report';

        link.innerHTML = '';
        L.DomEvent.on(link, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop)
                  .on(link, 'click', L.bind(this.startCreating, this));

        map.on("editable:drawing:commit", L.bind(this.onMarkerAdd, this));                    

        return container;
    },

    startCreating: function() {
        this.marker = this.map.editTools.startMarker();     
    },

    onMarkerAdd: function(e) {
        this.nearestFeature = null;
        this.findNearestPoints(e.layer.getLatLng());
    },

    onFormClosed: function() {
        if (this.marker!=null) {
            this.map.editTools.featuresLayer.removeLayer(this.marker);
            this.marker = null;
        }
    },

    findNearestPoints: function(latlng) {

         var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typeName: 'usa:within5mi',
            maxFeatures: 5,
            outputFormat: 'text/javascript', 
            format_options: 'callback: nearestPoints',
            srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
            viewparams: 'radius:802;lon:'+latlng.lng+';lat:'+latlng.lat,

        };

        var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);

        $.ajax({
            jsonp: false,
            url: this.options.url + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'nearestPoints',
            success: L.bind(this.handleNearestPoints, this)
        });         
    },


    handleNearestPoints: function(data) {           
        this.clearModal();
        this.setModalDate();

        if (data && data.type=="FeatureCollection"
            && data.features && data.features.length
            && data.features.length > 0) {
            this.fillModal(data.features[0]);
        }

        this.openPopup();
    },

    formatDate: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDate();
        return date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+(day < 10 ? "0"+day : day);
    },

    clearModal: function() {
        $('#eventDataModal2').find('input').each(
            function() {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        );

        $('#eventDataModal2').find('textarea').each(
            function() {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        );
    },

    setModalDate: function() {
        $("#form-patrolDate").val(this.formatDate(new Date()));
    },

    fillModal: function(feature) {
        var props = feature.properties;

        $("#form-region").val(props["Region"]);
        $("#form-circuitID").val(props["Circuit_ID"]);
        $("#form-circuitName").val(props["Circuit_Name"]);
        $("#form-vendor").val(props["Vendor"]);
        $("#form-quad").val(props["Quad"]);

    },

    openPopup: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
        $('#eventDataModal2').modal('show');
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        if (!this.binded) {
            $('#eventDataModal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', L.bind(this.onFormClosed, this));
            $("#saveEventDataModal2").on('click', L.bind(this.onSave, this))
            this.binded = true;
        }
    },

    onSave: function() {
        var properties = this.getFormData(),
            request = this.wfsBody("usa", "usa:pecotest", "geom", properties);
            console.log(request);
            this.makeRequest(request);          
    },

    makeRequest: function(body) {

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: this.options.url,
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "text",
            data: body,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(this.options.userName + ":" + this.options.password)
            },
            jsonpCallback: 'datasave',
            success: L.bind(this.onDataSave, this),
            failure: function(r){console.log("AJAX Failure!");console.log(r);}
        });                 
    },

    onDataSave: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },

    getFormData: function() {
        var result = {};

        $('#eventDataModal2').find('input').each(
            function() {
                if (this.type=="checkbox") {
                    result[this.name] = this.checked ? "Yes" : "No";    
                } else {
                    result[this.name]=$(this).val();
                }
            }
        );

        $('#eventDataModal2').find('textarea').each(
            function() {
                result[this.name]=$(this).val();
            }
        );

        return result;
    },

    wfsBody: function(namesapce, typeName, geometryField, properties) {
        var xml;
        xml ='<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"';
        xml += ' xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"';
        xml += ' xmlns:usa="http://census.gov"';
        xml += ' xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">\n';
        xml += '   <wfs:Insert>\n';
        xml += '      <'+typeName+'>\n';
        xml += '        <usa:'+geometryField+'>\n';
        xml += this.marker.toGML()+"\n";
        xml += '        </usa:'+geometryField+'>\n';

        for (var k in properties) {
            if (properties.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                xml += "<"+namesapce+":"+k+">";
                xml += properties[k];
                xml += "</"+namesapce+":"+k+">\n";
            }
        }

        xml += '      </'+typeName+'>\n';
        xml += '   </wfs:Insert>\n';
        xml += '</wfs:Transaction>\n';

        return xml;
    }

});
```

The corresponding HTML for eventDataModal is exactly the same as the above html code except the id has been changed to eventDataModal2

Comment: Creating a [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on  http://plnkr.co/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ would go a long way here

Comment: If leaflet modals are anything like most modals - you can only have a single instance as they are constructed using a singleton. Your IDs are irrelevant because the modal is manipulated through the modal class and gets populated with whatever content you first instantiate it with.

A way around this is to just update the data in that modal when the second link is clicked rather than trying to instantiate a new modal as it wont work. Trying to create a second modal will just return the first one you created.

Comment: so for example I should find a way to use data-toggle